# Earth Engine how to avoid timeout for buffer calculation?

Tags: google-earth-engine, function

I have a function that takes a feature and creates a buffer around it.

```
createBuffer = function(feature){

  var AOI = feature.geometry().buffer(3000);

  return ee.Feature(AOI).copyProperties(feature);
}
```

When I run this function on a collection that contains polygons that have  coastlines, the fractal nature of the coastline makes the buffering take a while, the result is delivered to another function to do imageCollection calculations based on the new buffered feature.

In some cases (though none that I can replicate here) it leads to a `The operation timed out.`

What can be done to avoid these timeouts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tries using simplify() on your geometry?

```
var AOI = feature.geometry().simplify(1000).buffer(3000);
```

It worked considarably faster and the buffer you create won't differ that much. At least, I tried it on a 4618 vertices linearRing I had. If your simplify maxError is smaller than your buffer size, the outcome won't be very different.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks.  The 'simplify()'  function solved the timeout issue.  Because it is a coastline, and the simplification of the vertices doesn't affect the outcome, as beyond it is the sea, the pixels there are of no effect to the calculation.